# How do I alter the opacity of an image to place it over another in java?

Tags: java, image, png

So I have the image of a map. And I have an image of an overlay which I want to place over the map such that you can see the map primarily but also the overlay. However on a pixel by pixel basis, I do not know how to evaluate the color of the resultant picture for it to be a mix of both the map and the overlay. For explanation purposes I made the following image: 
[image: sample image]

You can see The carrots mainly, but you can also see Donald Trump over top of the carrots. So given the RGB values (or HSV, whichever one is more useful) of each individual pixel of the whole image, how would I combine them in such a way that I can see both?

Comment: How is this not a repeat of your earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/32683202/2564301?

Comment: Because I am not interested in opacity. I'm only interested in mixing colors.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up solving this was by turning the RGB value of each pixel into an HSV color through the formula on http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm. Then I combined the Hue, Saturation, and Value values for each of the colors with whatever ratio I wanted and turned that HSV value back into RGB. I found that if I want to see one object more clearly than the other, you should preserve that object's Value value more. So since in my project I want to see the map more than the overlay, I matched the final Value value with that of the original map image.

Here's my code for the HSV color.

```
public static class HSVColor {
    double[] HSV = new double[3];
    int[] RGB = new int[3];
    int RGBV;
    //Constructor using the formula from http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm
    public HSVColor(int R, int G, int B) {
        RGB[0] = R;
        RGB[1] = G;
        RGB[2] = B;
        RGBV = (256 * 256) * R + 256 * G + B;
        double r = (double) R / 255.0;
        double g = (double) G / 255.0;
        double b = (double) B / 255.0;
        double min = Math.min(r, Math.min(g, b));
        double max = Math.max(r, Math.max(g, b));
        double delta = max - min;
        if (r == max) {
            HSV[0] = 60 * (((g - b) / delta) % 6);
        } else if (g == max) {
            HSV[0] = 60 * (((b - r) / delta) + 2);
        } else if (b == max) {
            HSV[0] = 60 * (((r - g) / delta) + 4);
        } else {
            HSV[0] = 0;
        }
        if (max == 0) {
            HSV[1] = 0;
        } else {
            HSV[1] = delta / max;
        }
        HSV[2] = max;
    }
    //Constructor using the formula from http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsv-to-rgb.htm
    public HSVColor(double H, double S, double V) {
        HSV[0] = H;
        HSV[1] = S;
        HSV[2] = V;
        double C = V * S;
        double X = C * (1 - Math.abs(((H / 60) % 2) - 1));
        double m = V - C;
        double r;
        double g;
        double b;
        if (H < 60) {
            r = C;
            g = X;
            b = 0;
        } else if (H < 120) {
            r = X;
            g = C;
            b = 0;
        } else if (H < 180) {
            r = 0;
            g = C;
            b = X;
        } else if (H < 240) {
            r = 0;
            g = X;
            b = C;
        } else if (H < 300) {
            r = X;
            g = 0;
            b = C;
        } else {
            r = C;
            g = 0;
            b = X;
        }
        RGB[0] = (int) ((r + m) * 255);
        RGB[1] = (int) ((g + m) * 255);
        RGB[2] = (int) ((b + m) * 255);
        RGBV = (256 * 256) * RGB[0] + 256 * RGB[1] + RGB[2];
    }
}
```